# Is it possible to reverse the XOR of multiple variables?

Tags: encryption, xor

A function computes the XOR sum of binary numbers.  The numbers come from a finite set of "n" constants, whose values are fixed and known (without repeats). The function is passed a subset of  these constants and returns the XOR sum.

Question: Given the XOR sum, the value of the n constants, and without knowing how many were combined to produce the output, is it possible to tell which of the "n" constants were input to the function to produce that output?   I am aware that if you knew in advance there were only 2 inputs, the solution is trivial:  just XOR each of the n constants to the output one at a time to see if you get one of the others.  If it does, you have found both.  I just can't see how this applies to the general case of 2 to n inputs.

I tried XORing each value to the output one at a time to see if the result was "special" in some way when that value was in the subset of inputs, compared to when it was not.  That didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2<sup>n</sup> combinations of values (for each value it is either included or it is not). So this is solvable in O(2<sup>n</sup>) in the worst case. This is identical to the answer you already noted for n=2. Just keep doing it.

You can optimize this and look at each bit independently. For example, if the first bit is 1, then there must be an odd number of items that have 1 in their first position. Conversely if the first bit is 0, there must be an even number of items. This would allow you to dramatically shrink the search space since only certain combinations are possible. But it's definitely solvable in finite time.

At the extreme end of this optimization, consider the case that there is a 1 in a position, and only one of the values in your set also has a 1 in that position. Clearly that value is included. You can XOR it against the target, and repeat the process.

Comment: Thanks.  For small n, the brute force approach is certainly do-able as you suggest. However, (i should have mentioned this) n=40, so 2^40 is HUGE.  The numbers are all 40 bits long and have a minimum of 8, maximum of 30 "1's", (average =20).  None of the numbers has a "1" exclusively in any position.    Knowing BOTH the number set  AND the function, should make this easy but it's not.  I've pretty much exhausted XORing the numbers, their complements, the XOR of the entire set, etc, trying to take advantage of  A^A = 0, A^NOT A= 1, A^B^B=A, A^1= NOT A, etc, but no luck.

Comment: @opua: There is a trivial meet-in-the-middle attack that takes O(2^(n/2)), so 2^20 steps. If T = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 then c1 + c2 + T = c3 + c4, where "+" is xor. Generalizes to larger n.

Comment: "Knowing BOTH the number set AND the function, should make this easy but it's not." While there are efficient (by efficient, I mean "faster than brute force") attacks on this algorithm, and it is not a secure algorithm, there is certainly no reason to believe that knowing the numbers and function should make this easy. Most modern cryptographic functions are based on the premise that functions exist that are difficult to undo when missing a single piece of information.

Comment: Also, 2^40 is only about 1 trillion. That's a quite small search space, especially for such a low-cost operation as XOR. Have you tried brute forcing it? (To put 2^40 in perspective, we generally measure GPU performance in trillions of floating-point operations **per second**.)

Comment: I understand how XOR'ing  c1 and c2 to T leaves c3 and c4.  I just don't see how that cuts the number of trials in half.   Can you expand the process to multiple steps?   Even so, 2^20 trials takes too long (I know for a fact that the constants can be discovered in less than a second,  by a run-of-the-mill, low speed microcontroller.   This makes me think there is a trick, trapdoor, or shortcut made possible by careful selection of the set of 40 constants.   The table of numbers does reveal some curious patterns in some areas but otherwise looks random.

Comment: @opua: It doesn't cut it in half, it square roots the number of trials. You can read about the attack at [Meet-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack). I'm not claiming that this is the fastest attack, I'm just offering another possibility. As pointed out in the other comment, the XORs should be very fast, so the time for this attack would be dominated by the hash function used in the hash table. A carefully chosen hash function should make this doable in much less than a second even on low-end processors.

Comment: When you look at the actual set of constants as a spreadsheet of 1's and 0's, it's curious to see 4 groups of 3- 6 numbers that are simply 1-bit shifts of each other (MSB wraps to LSB).  Why go to the trouble?  Wouldn't random numbers be more secure?  Is there a way I can post the table of numbers?

Comment: The processor I know of that is able to discover the constants (quickly), does so with less than 256 bytes of storage.   Doesn't that rule out a Man-in-the-middle attack?

Comment: This seems to be wandering from a general "Is it possible to reverse the XOR of multiple variables?" to a question of "what specific approach will crack this particular system." This may be straying beyond a StackOverflow question. This is not a reverse engineer or cracking site. Is there a general question here that would be of use to others, or are you looking for cryptography consulting on a specific problem?